# $\mathscr C[0,1]$ with $\|f\|_L := |f(0)| + \sup_{0\le x < y\le 1} \frac{|f(y) - f(x)|}{y-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Consider the Banach space $\mathscr C[0,1]$ consisting of all continuous, real valued functions on $[0,1]$, endowed with the uniform norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$. For $f\in \mathscr C[0,1]$, let $$\|f\|_L := |f(0)| + \sup_{0\le x < y\le 1} \frac{|f(y) - f(x)|}{y-x}$$
>
> 1. Show that $A = \{f\in \mathscr C[0,1]: \|f\|_L \le 1\}$ is compact in $\mathscr C[0,1]$.
> 2. Is the set $B = \{f\in \mathscr C[0,1]: \|f\|_L < \infty\}$ dense in $\mathscr C[0,1]$ or not?

My attempt:

1. To show that $A$ is compact, my strategy is to show that every sequence in $A$ has a converging subsequence. Let $\{f_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence in $A$. We have $\|f_n\|_L \le 1$ for each $n\ge 1$, giving $|f_n(0)| \le 1$ and $\sup_{0\le x < y\le 1} \frac{|f_n(y) - f_n(x)|}{y-x} \le 1$ for each $n\ge 1$. I'm not sure how to extract a converging subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}_{k\ge 1}$ with this information.
2. I suspect that $B$ is dense in $\mathscr C[0,1]$. I have made an observation. Any $f\in \mathscr C[0,1]$ is uniformly continuous, so for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ ensures $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. Pick $\epsilon = 1$ and choose a corresponding $\delta < 1$. We can divide $I = [0,1]$ into $\left\lceil \frac{2}{\delta} \right\rceil$ intervals each of size $<\delta$. I was hoping to use this to somehow get a bound on $\sup_{0\le x < y\le 1} \frac{|f(y) - f(x)|}{y-x}$, but it didn't work.

P.S. Even though this is just a qualifying exam problem, I'm interested to know the motivation behind defining $\|\cdot\|_L$ on $\mathscr C[0,1]$ - the definition is somewhat mysterious.

Comment: First part is an easy consequence of Arzela-Ascoli Theorem. Second part follows from Weirstrass Theorem since polynomials belong to $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the space of Lipschitz-continuous functions (hence the $L$). More generally, rather than $|x-y|$, if you put $|x-y|^{\alpha}$ with $0<\alpha\leq 1$, then you get the space of Holder continuous functions. The extra sup term you’re adding is the ‘smallest Lipschitz constant’.

- Arzela-Ascoli, is almost always the answer here.
- For (2), note that every $C^1$ function on $[0,1]$ is Lipschitz-continuous (by the mean-value theorem), so $\|f\|_L\leq |f(0)|+\|f’\|_{C([0,1])}<\infty$ ($f’$ is continuous on the compact interval $[0,1]$ so the supremum is finite by the extreme-value theorem). So, $C^1[0,1]\subset B$. Why does this help? I’m not sure how many approximation theorems you know, but even the set of polynomials (which are obviously $C^1$) is dense, by Weierstrass’ approximation theorem.